# Find the product of elements located between the maximum and minimum elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, a, b,min,max, Prod = 1, Sum = 0;
    cout << "Initialize an array n: ";
    cin >> n;
    do
    {
        cout << "Input the start value: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Input the end value: ";
        cin >> b;
        if (!(a < b))
        {
            cout << "a is bigger than b, please enter new values " << endl;
            continue;
        }
    } while (!(a < b));

    int* lpi_arr;
    lpi_arr = new int[n];

    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Int numbers from " << a << " to " << b << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        lpi_arr[i] = rand() % (b - a) + a;
        cout << lpi_arr[i] << " ";
    }

    max = lpi_arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (max < lpi_arr[i])
            max = lpi_arr[i];
    }
    min = lpi_arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (min > lpi_arr[i])
            min = lpi_arr[i];
    }

    cout << "\nmin element is = " << min << endl;
    cout << "\nmax element is = " << max << endl;

    for (int i = max + 1; i < min; i++)
        Prod *= lpi_arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; lpi_arr[i] < 0 && i < n; i++)
        Sum += lpi_arr[i];

    cout << "Summ =" << Sum << endl << "Prod = " << Prod << endl;

    delete[] lpi_arr; 
}
```

The main purpose of this code is to calculate the sum of negative numbers of an array, and multiplication of elements located between the maximum and minimum elements of an array.

The problem is that the code implements only 1(one) as an answer, and I don't know how to change it. Every other part of the code works well, but if you have any recommendations I'd also like to read it. Waiting for your help.

Comment: "code implements only 1(one) as an answer": what does this mean?

Comment: In this line:  `for (int i = max + 1; i < min; i++)` when would max+1 be less than min?

Comment: @drescherjm I think when the index of the maximum value is higher than the index of the minimum value..... but that is only guessing....

Comment: fwiw, good names are difficult, but it always pays off to spend some time on it. `max_value` and `max_index` rather than just `max` would have made the mistake obvious

Comment: On a side note: `(!(a < b))` should be written as `(a >= b)` instead. Also consider using a C++ RNG from [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) rather than the C-style `rand()`. Also consider using [`std::minmax_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to find the min/max elements, and [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to calculate the sum and product, rather than using manual loops. Also consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) rather than `new[]`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `continue` doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: `... } while(a >= b && cout << "a >=b, enter new values\n");` would remove the need for the check inside the loop and the microoptimization `continue`. Of course, if `cout` is closed, it could get ugly ... A cleaner option: `while(true) { ... if(a < b) break; cout << "a >= b, enter new values\n"; }`

Comment: To solve the issue, you could make a `max_index` and `min_index` variables initialized to 0 and set `max_index` to `i` when you set `max = lpi_arr[i];` and similar for `min_index` when you do `min = lpi_arr[i];` remember when you put more than 1 line in the statement of the if () you want to add { and } to form a block around the 2 statements. Then use max_index and min_index in your for () that I told you was wrong.

Comment: *The problem is that the code implements only 1(one) as an answer, and I don't know how to change it.* -- You shouldn't be introducing random data in a program that is broken.  Use known data that causes the issue.  By using random data, you are changing the data on each run, thus making it harder to debug the issue.

Comment: BTW, using `std::minmax_element` and `std::accumulate` makes this a 3 or 4 line C++ program, without any hand-coded loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you're confusing array indexes with array values.

Here you're assigning `max` (and same with `min`) to an array *value*.

```
max = lpi_arr[i];
```

Here you're treating `max` (and same with `min`) as an array *index*.

```
for (int i = max + 1; i < min; i++)
    Prod *= lpi_arr[i];
```

Comment: could you help me how can i rewrite it using min max as an array value

Comment: @arcend If I were you, I'd go the other way, actually. Have `max`/`min` be array indexes all the way through. I won't write the code for you, but if you have a specific problem getting that working, you could open another question.